# regex, preg_replace: replacing multiple instances with single

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I have auto generated string.

One of its elements is a group "/__nh".

Sometimes it is being multiplied, e.g.:

```
$string = some_stuff_here/__nh/__nh/__nh
```

I tried code below (and some other variation as well) to replace replace multiple instances with a single one:

```
return preg_replace('/(//__nh)+/', '/__nh', $string);
```

.. but I failed (regex is not something I'm comfortable with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape your forward slash using a backslash, not another forward slash:

```
return preg_replace('/(\/__nh)+/', '/__nh', $string);
```

Comment: I see, wrong escape used by me - probably this heat wave we have in UK at present could be blamed :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a double slash on your regex?

Shouldn't it be a back slash ?

Anyways: a greaat regex reference is: http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php